# Ingres Database - CTE query is not working

Tags: sql, database, etl, ingres, actian

I am trying to implement a CTE in Ingres Databaseas below

```
 with sample_cte(email) as(
     select distinct email_address as email from table1)
 select email from sample_cte;
```

But i am getting below Error when executing this query.Can anyone please help

```
Error : Query or Procedure returns a result set
SQLState: 21000
ErrorCode :802840
```

Can anyone help on this

Comment: What happens if you just do the `select distinct email_address as email from table1` standalone?

Comment: @jarlh , it is returning the resul

Comment: i can see similar issue reported by another user https://communities.actian.com/s/question/0D5f300004rQ5ocCAC/sql-error-802840-21000-query-or-procedure-returns-a-result-set-using-actian-vector-50

Comment: The syntax worked fine with e.g. Actian X/Ingres 11.2, so are you using some old version? Can you move to a supported version?

Comment: i think issue is squirrel that i am trying to connect